# Anidar bucles For X cantidad de veces

Tags: python, bucle-for

Cómo yo pudiera anidar bucles For un número indeterminado de veces en Python?
O sea, que la cantidad de bucles For Anidados dependa de un número introducido en la ejecución del programa.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!  esto se puede hacer en cualquier lenguaje... la respuesta es si. que intentaste y que problema tuviste?

Comment: Es algo muy raro lo que buscas, ¿para que necesitas hacer algo como esto? ¿qué es lo que buscas realmente?

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo con las normas, deberías publicar algo de código antes de recibir una respuesta. Sin embargo, este problema es recurrente, bien definido e interesante y merece una respuesta. Pido la comprensión del resto.

**Solución número fijo de `for`**

Partamos por examinar un problema con varios `for` anidados. Para acortar, pongamos este tonto problema, que consiste en acumular repetidas veces `2 + 4`.

```
suma = 0
for i1 in range(2):
    for i2 in range(3):
        for i3 in range(4):
            suma += 2 + 4
print("suma=", suma)
```

produce:

```
suma= 144
```

**Solución número indeterminado de `for`**

Esta solución aplica para `for` del tipo `for i in range(x):`

Primero, tengo que sacar el cuerpo del `for` más interno y ponerlo en una función que reciba vía parámetros y/o variables globales los valores con que debe operar:

```
def fcn_ejemplo(a, b):
    global suma
    suma += a + b
```

Cada uno de los `for` tendrá un limite, los que guardare en una lista:

```
limites = [2, 3, 4]
```

La lista puede tener cualquier largo, lo que nos asegura que podemos manejar un número arbitrario de `for` anidados.

Ahora construyo una función `new_for` recursiva que recibe la lista de indices, además de la función a evaluar y sus parámetros.

`new_for` revisara si la lista es de largo uno. En tal caso, ejecuta un ciclo `for` llamando a la función recibida como parámetro.

Si la lista tiene más de un elemento, ejecuta un `for` llamándose a si misma. En la llamada pasa la lista de indices sin su primer elemento. Así la lista se va acortando.

```
nivel_for = 0
suma = 0

def fcn_ejemplo(a, b):
    global suma
    suma += a + b

def new_for(limite, f, *args):
    global nivel_for

    nivel_for += 1
    if len(limite) == 1:
        print(" " * nivel_for, end="")
        print("nivel=", nivel_for, "for i in range(", limite[0], "):")
        for idx in range(limite[-1]):
            f(*args)
    else:
        for idx in range(limite[0]):
            print(" " * nivel_for, end="")
            print("nivel=", nivel_for, " idx = ", idx)
            new_for(limite[1:], f, *args)

    nivel_for -= 1
```

y la usamos asi:

```
limites = [2, 3, 4]
new_for(limites, fcn_ejemplo, 2, 4)
print("suma=", suma)
```

produce:

```
 nivel= 1  idx =  0
  nivel= 2  idx =  0
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
  nivel= 2  idx =  1
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
  nivel= 2  idx =  2
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
 nivel= 1  idx =  1
  nivel= 2  idx =  0
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
  nivel= 2  idx =  1
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
  nivel= 2  idx =  2
   nivel= 3 for i in range( 4 ):
suma= 144
```

La variable `nivel_for` es innecesaria, lo mismo que los `print`. La pongo simplemente para ayudar a la comprensión de la ejecución.

Este sería el método básico. La función `f` tiene que ser adaptada para realizar la aplicación en particular.

Comment: Gracias. Tu respuesta me ha servido mucho.